# Pandas groupby two columns get earliest date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting, group-by

[This is the dataset:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5AV9o.png)

`

```
data = {'id': ['1','1','1','1','2','2','2','2','2','3','3','3','3','3','3','3'],
                      'status': ['Active','Active','Active','Pending Action','Pending Action','Pending Action','Active','Pending Action','Active','Draft','Active','Draft','Draft','Draft','Active','Draft'],
                      'calc_date_id':['05/07/2022','07/06/2022','31/08/2021','01/07/2021','20/11/2022','25/10/2022','02/04/2022','28/02/2022','01/07/2021','23/06/2022','15/06/2022','07/04/2022','09/11/2022','18/08/2020','19/03/2020','17/01/202']
        }                

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
#to datetime
df['calc_date_id'] = pd.to_datetime(df['calc_date_id'])
```

`

How do I get the first date in the last time the status change by id?

I tried sorting by date and groupby with id and status and keep="first" but I got:

[Groupbing by status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/is8J6.png)

Also tried

```
df_mt_date.loc[df_mt_date.groupby(['id',' status'])['calc_date_id'].idxmin()]
```

Instead of that I'd like to preserve the order by date obtaining only the first time where the id has changed status for the last time (not all of the history).

[This is the desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sia6E.png)

I'm running out of ideas, I'll appreciate any suggestion

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
df["desired_output"] = df.groupby("id")["status"].transform(
    lambda x: df.loc[x.index, "calc_date_id"][(x != x.shift(-1)).idxmax()]
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   id          status calc_date_id desired_output
0   1          Active   2022-07-05     2021-08-31
1   1          Active   2022-06-07     2021-08-31
2   1          Active   2021-08-31     2021-08-31
3   1  Pending Action   2021-07-01     2021-08-31
4   2  Pending Action   2022-11-20     2022-10-25
5   2  Pending Action   2022-10-25     2022-10-25
6   2          Active   2022-04-02     2022-10-25
7   2  Pending Action   2022-02-28     2022-10-25
8   2          Active   2021-07-01     2022-10-25
9   3           Draft   2022-06-23     2022-06-23
10  3          Active   2022-06-15     2022-06-23
11  3           Draft   2022-04-07     2022-06-23
12  3           Draft   2022-11-09     2022-06-23
13  3           Draft   2020-08-18     2022-06-23
14  3          Active   2020-03-19     2022-06-23
15  3           Draft   2020-01-17     2022-06-23
```

Answer (score 0):

From your desired output I see, that the group "boundaries" are
points where particular value of *status* column occurs for the
first time, regardless of *id* column.

To indicate first occurrences of values in *status* column, run:

```
wrk = df.groupby('status', group_keys=False).apply(
    lambda grp: grp.assign(isFirst=grp.index[0] == grp.index))
wrk.isFirst = wrk.isFirst.cumsum()
```

To see the result, print *wrk* and look at *isFirst* column.

Then, to generate the result, run:

```
result = wrk.groupby('isFirst', group_keys=False).apply(
    lambda grp: grp.assign(desired_output=grp.calc_date_id.min()))\
    .drop(columns='isFirst')
```

Note the terminating *drop* to drop now unnecessary *isFirst* column.

The result, for your data sample, is:

```
   id          status calc_date_id desired_output
0   1          Active   2022-07-05     2021-08-31
1   1          Active   2022-06-07     2021-08-31
2   1          Active   2021-08-31     2021-08-31
3   1  Pending Action   2021-07-01     2021-07-01
4   2  Pending Action   2022-11-20     2021-07-01
5   2  Pending Action   2022-10-25     2021-07-01
6   2          Active   2022-04-02     2021-07-01
7   2  Pending Action   2022-02-28     2021-07-01
8   2          Active   2021-07-01     2021-07-01
9   3           Draft   2022-06-23     2020-03-19
10  3          Active   2022-06-15     2020-03-19
11  3           Draft   2022-04-07     2020-03-19
12  3           Draft   2022-11-09     2020-03-19
13  3           Draft   2020-08-18     2020-03-19
14  3          Active   2020-03-19     2020-03-19
15  3           Draft   2022-01-17     2020-03-19
```